# Java 2D array diagonals for game

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array, logic, diagonal

To clarify I only wanted one or two for loops to help me on my way, preferably in the same style as I had used in the vertical :)

I'm making a game using a 2D array, and I need a check that tests if at the current position (indicated by a green square) the character there is part of a diagonal sequence of "l" more of the character.

Comment: The diagonal sequence has to be only on the main diagonals of the graph or it can be anywhere on the graph ?

Comment: Sorry, just realised there isn't really one, but it'd be great if someone could give me a for loop to perform 1 of the 4 actions needed :)

Comment: It can be anywhere on the graph depending on the length specified given to "l" for example it is not possible to have a minor diagonal of length 5 near the bottom right hand corner of the grid.

Comment: Oh and the current position has to be part of the sequence, dunno if I clarified that.

Comment: You should add a question to your post. Also: Normally, code request are not part of SO, I just answered out of interest... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean diagonals(char[][] b, int row, int col, int l) {

            int counter = 1; // because we start from the current position
            char charAtPosition = b[row][col];
            int numRows = b.length;
            int numCols = b[0].length;
            int topleft = 0;
            int topright = 0;
            int bottomleft = 0;
            int bottomright = 0;
            for (int i=row-1,j=col-1;i>=0 && j>=0;i--,j--) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    topleft++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i=row-1,j=col+1;i>=0 && j<=numCols;i--,j++) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    topright++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i=row+1,j=col-1;i<=numRows && j>=0;i++,j--) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    bottomleft++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i=row+1,j=col+1;i<=numRows && j<=numCols;i++,j++) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    bottomright++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return topleft + bottomright + 1 >= l || topright + bottomleft + 1 >= l; //in this case l is 5
    }
```

The idea is that we walk in four directions and count the steps. This may not be the most efficient implementation, but at least it looks neat and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function, it works. The explanation is in the comments in the code, but if you find anything confusing let me know and I'll explain it.

```
public static boolean diagonals(char[][] b, int row, int col, int l) {
  int forwardCounter = 1; // this counts top right to bottom left
  int backCounter = 1; // this counts top left to bottom right
  int distance = 1;
  // 0 = topleft, 1 = topright, 2 = bottomleft, 3 = bottomright
  boolean[] checks = new boolean[]{true, true, true, true};

  char charAtPosition = b[row][col];

  while(checks[0] || checks[1] || checks[2] || checks[3]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(checks[i]) {
        // This looks confusing but it's simply just converting i into
        // The four different directions
        checks[i] = checkSquare(b, row + (i < 2 ? -distance : distance),
                col + (i % 2 == 0 ? -distance : distance), charAtPosition);
        if(checks[i]) {
          // If top left or bottom right
          if(i % 3 == 0) {
            backCounter++;
          } else {
            forwardCounter++;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (forwardCounter >= l || backCounter >= l) return true;

    distance++;
  }

  return false;
}

private static boolean checkSquare(char[][] b, int row, int col, char check) {
  if(row < 0 || row >= b.length) return false;
  if(col < 0 || col >= b[0].length) return false;

  return check == b[row][col];
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of nesting. :D

Comment: @brimborium: not really, the `for` loop does the job of your four `if` statements, just because I like to be more confusing to remove copy-paste of code ;)

Comment: I didn't critized, I just stated a fact. You are basically doing the same thing as I do. :) (Although I like my boundary check more as it uses less checks)

Comment: brimorium: ah :) Anyway I tested this, it works, on at least the two examples that @Ciphor posted

Comment: Just tested your code. Works well. I deleted mine because of OP's comment: `Added a previous method which does the same for a vertical, maybe you can adjust it? – Ciphor`

Comment: Should be easy to merge the two functions (run one, then the other). Of course one could modify my code to use 8 booleans and mess around with the math...